# AJAX search not returning anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I changed both of your suggestions. The address bar didn't change before so I'm not really sure what's going on at the moment. When I click Search now nothing appears in the search_results div and the address bar changes to:

> index.php?habbo_name=test&send=Search

Current index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Personnel Tracking System - E-3+</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script language="JavaScript">
    function tS(){ x=new Date(tN().getUTCFullYear(),tN().getUTCMonth(),tN().getUTCDate(),tN().getUTCHours(),tN().getUTCMinutes(),tN().getUTCSeconds()); x.setTime(x.getTime()); return x; }
    function tN(){ return new Date(); }
    function lZ(x){ return (x>9)?x:'0'+x; }
    function y2(x){ x=(x<500)?x+1900:x; return String(x).substring(2,4) }
    function dT(){ if(fr==0){ fr=1; document.write('<font size=2 face=Arial color=white><b><span id="tP">'+eval(oT)+'</span></b></font>'); } document.getElementById('tP').innerHTML=eval(oT); setTimeout('dT()',1000); }
    var mN=new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'),fr=0,oT="tS().getDate()+' '+mN[tS().getMonth()]+' '+y2(tS().getYear())+' '+':'+':'+' '+lZ(tS().getHours())+':'+lZ(tS().getMinutes())+':'+lZ(tS().getSeconds())+' '";
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#search_habbos").bind('submit',function() {
        $.post( "search_results.php", { value: $('#habbo_name').val() })
            .done(function( data ) {
              $("#search_results").html(data);
            });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $.fn.snow();
  });
</script>

<div id="navbar">
  <img src="images/logo.png" style="position: absolute; top: 7px; left: 50px;" />
  <center>
    <img class="navbar" src="images/homebutton.png" />
    <img class="navbar" src="images/e-3button.png" />
    <img class="navbar" src="images/resignedbutton.png" />
    <img class="navbar" src="images/firedbutton.png" />
    <img class="navbar" src="images/desertersbutton.png" />
    <img class="navbar" src="images/mosrosterbutton.png" />
    <img src="images/divider.png" />
    <p><script language="JavaScript">dT();</script></p>
  </center>
</div>

<div id="search">
  <center>
    <b><p>Search</p></b>
    <form action="" id="search_habbos">
      <input type="text" name="habbo_name" id="habbo_name" size="30">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" name="send" id="send">
    </form>
  </center>
  <div id="search_results"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Current search_results.php:

```
<?php
    global $con;
        $habbo_name_final = '%'.$_POST['value'].'%';

        if (empty($_POST) === false) {
            global $con;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `personnel` WHERE `habbo_name` LIKE :search ORDER BY `habbo_name`";
            $result = $con->prepare($query);
            $result->bindParam(':search', $habbo_name_final, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();

            while($row = $result->fetch()) {
                echo "<b>" . htmlspecialchars($row['status']) . ":</b> &nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['habbo_name']) . "</b> &nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['rank']) . "&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['rating']) . "&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['tag']) . "&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['asts']) . "&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['promotion_date']) . "&nbsp <b>" . htmlspecialchars($row['rdc_grade']) . "</b> &nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['medals']) . htmlspecialchars($row['transfer_rank_received']) . "&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['cnl_trainings']) . "&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['fired_reason']) . htmlspecialchars($row['desert_date']) . htmlspecialchars($row['quit_date']) . htmlspecialchars($row['fired_tag']) . "&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['fired_date']) . "<br />";
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Enter a search term!';
        }   
        if (empty($row) == false) {
            echo "No results found";
        }
?>
```

Comment: you are missing a ; on line 3 as the script suggests..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you meant to do with this (mysql, plop in a variable, etc).

**Line #3 of your PHP:**

```
$habbo_name = '".$_POST['value']."'
```

*First*, need a semicolon`;`.

*Then*, move the inner double quotes to be around `value`.  Essentially this gives `$habbo_name` an exact value of `".$_POST[` and then it errors out because you killed the expression early and PHP sees `value` and flips out.

### Corrected:

```
$habbo_name_final = '%' . $_POST["value"] . '%';
```

No need to use two variables here.  One will do just fine.  This is similar to the answer below me but his will not parse either because he exits early like you did on the expression.

EDIT:

Your entire page looks like it's from 1998.  Too many things to point out so we're skipping that.

To troubleshoot, move the whole AJAX expression to the end of the page and try using this instead of what you have now:

```
$('#search_habbos').bind('submit', function() {
    $.post('search_results.php', { value: $('#habbo_name').val() }, function( data ) {
        $('#search_results').prepend( data );
    });
});
```

And I'm pretty sure your SQL query needs two little `' '`s.

```
"SELECT * FROM `personnel` WHERE `habbo_name` LIKE :search ORDER BY `habbo_name`";
```

Needs to be:

```
"SELECT * FROM `personnel` WHERE `habbo_name` LIKE ':search' ORDER BY `habbo_name`";
```

Let us know how that works for you

Comment: It still doesn't return anything in the div and changes the address bar to what I put in my main post.. any ideas?

Comment: I didn't read your code all the way through apparently.  Go change `value` to `habbo_name`

Comment: Same thing still happening o.O

Comment: OK try that stuff out and let us know im gonna get some drank

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43212/discussion-between-deryck-and-user2547576)

Comment: I've updated the main post to show what I've got now. I'm still having the same problem. Address bar is changing to ?habbo_name=test&send=Search if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery link with this new address in top of your page

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

In your jquery code do this

```
    $.post( "search_results.php", { value: $('#habbo_name').val() })
     .done(function( data ) {
          $("#search_results").html(data);
    });
```

No need of **var value = $('#habbo_name').val();** and in your php code try this

```
  $habbo_name_final = '%'.$_POST['value'].'%';
```

no need of **$habbo_name** variable

Comment: I now get this:

Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\personnel\search_results.php on line 3

Followed by 'Enter a search term!'

Comment: ok now it means that $_POST['value'] is not sent. Let me check you js code

Comment: yes! but remember to change php code as well. what are you having now?

Comment: Well now finally i found error that you were having. Update your Jquery source link like in above code i have shown. Actually our code was working perfectly but only problem was that **.done** method was not supported in your attached jquery file.